# How can I do replace the id or class for HTML elements in HTML fragments?

Tags: ruby, parsing, html-parsing, nokogiri

I need to check an HTML fragment and replace the ids or classes of HTML elements with other values. Using a regexp doesn't fit my needs because there can be multiple occurrences of the searched-for class in the text, which I should keep.

For example, I have this HTML:

```
<div id='sweet'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
```

When I replace `id='sweet'` with 'bitter' I want to receive:

```
<div id='bitter'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
```

I can do it with Nokogiri without any problems, but sometimes I get invalid HTML and need to return the markup as it was. The problem is, Nokogiri fixes markup and broken nodes.

Example:

```
</table>
<div id='sweet'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
```

I will receive only this:

```
<div id='bitter'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
</div>
<div id='sweet'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text
```

I will get this:

```
<div id='bitter'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get this from the second example?:

```
</div>
<div id='bitter'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text
```

Comment: You can't expect a parser like Nokogiri to return broken HTML after its parsed the document, and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexes, but with a little more context:

```
str = "</div>
<div id='sweet'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text"

str.sub /id='sweet'/, "id='bitter'"
```

will only change the first instance of 'sweet'.

Similarly,

```
str = "</div>
<div class='cls1 sweet cls3'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text"

puts str.sub( /class=['"]([^'"]*)sweet([^'"]*)['"]/ ) { "class='#{$1}bitter#{$2}'" }
```

handles 'sweet' only within a class attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this work. I just a little modified your code to handle attribute (class or id) and return the same quotes <"> or <'>      `str.gsub( /#{attr_type}=(['"])([^'"]*)#{old_selector}([^'"]*)(['"])/im ) { "#{type}=#{$1}#{$2}#{new_selector}#{$3}#{$4}"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious answer is:

```
str = <<EOF
</div>
<div id='sweet'>
  Bla bla sweet bla bla...
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text
EOF

str['sweet'] = 'bitter'
puts str
```

Comment: Maybe with ID is a bad example, because it should not be more that one  time in document. For example there can be many <li class='sweet'> elements and I must replace them all to <li class='bitter'>. How to be in this situation?